# Codeigniter Array Display

Tags: codeigniter, co

I want to display values of an array, but it only displays one value of the array rather than all values of the array.

Model:

```
function get_subject_position($exam_id , $class_id , $subject_id ) {

        $this->db->where('exam_id' , $exam_id);
        $this->db->where('class_id' , $class_id);
        $this->db->where('subject_id' , $subject_id);
        $this->db->select('mark_obtained');
        $this->db->order_by('mark_obtained DESC');
        $subject_position = $this->db->get('mark')->result_array();
        foreach($subject_position as $row) {

             return $row;     
        }
        }
```

View:

```
$subject_pos = $this->crud_model->get_subject_position($row2['exam_id'], $class_id, $row3['subject_id']);

<td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $subject_pos['mark_obtained'];?></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the "foreach" loop into your view, because right now it's returning the first $row, and then stopping the foreach loop ("return" stops looping)

Example:

View

```
<?php
$subject_pos = $this->crud_model->get_subject_position($row2['exam_id'], $class_id, $row3['subject_id']);
foreach($subject_pos as $row) {
?>
<tr>
    <td style="text-align: center;"><?=$row['mark_obtained']?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Function

```
function get_subject_position($exam_id , $class_id , $subject_id ) {

    $this->db->where('exam_id' , $exam_id);
    $this->db->where('class_id' , $class_id);
    $this->db->where('subject_id' , $subject_id);
    $this->db->select('mark_obtained');
    $this->db->order_by('mark_obtained DESC');

    return $this->db->get('mark')->result_array(); // Get ALL rows

    }
```

Comment: you does'n send the result array return statement should be like this  return $this->db->get('mark')->result_array();

Comment: Thanks so much am grateful

Comment: I want to use array_search() to find position of score in each subject, its not working i will ask a new question